# Best way to resolve svn "Two top-level reports with no target"

Tags: svn, version-control

I have an svn repo

```
http://path/to/svn/trunk
```

And have branched a few things from it to

```
http://path/to/svn/branch
```

By using

```
svn copy http://path/to/svn/trunk/site1 http://path/to/svn/branch/site1 -m 'message'
```

I've done a lot of work on the branch but havent merged it back in, as it isn't ready for that.

However, I need to commit changes to trunk now, and I'm getting the following when attempting to do so

```
> svn commit -m 'some message'
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: '/path/to/svn/trunk' remains in tree-conflict
```

I thought I should `svn up` on the /path/to/trunk but the following happens

```
> svn up
svn: Two top-level reports with no target
```

A `--force` doesn't help remedy the situation.

`svn status` results in lots of +'s next to the changed files

```
> svn status
M  +    site1/changedfile
```

Has anyone experienced this before, and can you shed some light on the issue at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I managed to resolve this was by moving the affected directories in `/path/to/svn/trunk` to a temporary location, and did an `svn up` on trunk.

This pulled in older versions of my files. I then manually copied the files that couldn't get committed across, and once they were back in place everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me after a botched `svn mv https://path1 https://path2`:

```
svn revert --depth infinity path2
svn update path2
```

This avoided me having to do the fresh checkout that others have suggested.  None of my changes were lost in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a Google search, the answers (e.g. [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022/phantom-directories-in-an-svn-repository)) suggest that you made some changes that upset svn (e.g. made a modification to a file, then moved it without committing in-between).

The best fix I could find so far is to make a fresh check-out of trunk, manually merge changes to it (e.g. via WinMerge if you are on Windows) -- making commits on the way between different kinds of changes to the same file/directory -- from your current working copy; then commit that checkout.  (At this point you can either replace your current working copy with this modified fresh checkout or discard all changes in the working copy and do an update on it to make it in-sync with the changes you have just committed)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for a way to solve this problem without doing a fresh checkout.

Comment: @darryn.ten - Just out of curiosity: What's wrong with the fresh copy approach?

Comment: Lack of disk space, the size of the trunk and the speed (haha) of svn.

Answer (score 0):

The 'S' marks a switched URL state - the URL of the directory doesn't correspond to your current working directory. This may be due to a merge or a switch that didn't complete its operation. In this scenario I usually do the following:

For the following steps, let the directory 'problem_dir' be the affected directory.

Firstly I find out where the directories have switched too

```
svn info problem_dir
```

If it points to another URL, then switch to the URL you want it to point to:

```
svn switch ^/trunk/problem_dir problem_dir
```

Once all directories are pointing to the correct URL, you can revert and update:

```
svn revert . -R
svn update
```

Important! Only do a recursive revert once you have committed working changes.

If this doesn't work, then the last resort would be

```
rm -rf .
svn update
```